# Can I disable the F5 refresh for terminal windows?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Last weekend I happily upgraded (reinstalled) to Elementary 6. I have two issues (one is often discussed... can't get the system tray icons for owncloud etc working... will get that working in the end as I did with previous versions of Elementary).

The other one is that I'm a happy user of mc (for years and year) within the terminal. Mc uses F5 to copy files. The terminal in 6 wants to do a refresh of the terminal. Can I disable the refresh function? Now I have to use an extra button the let mc copy a file and my muscle memory doesn't understand that... I couldn't find any settings for the terminal window that allow me to disable the F5-refresh. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. There doesn't seem to be an easy switch (yet), but I was able to turn it off by editing the source code.

1.) Go to https://github.com/elementary/terminal and download the sources with

```
git clone https://github.com/elementary/terminal.git
```

2.) Inside the source directory, open the file "src/MainWindow.vala" and search for the following line:

```
action_accelerators[ACTION_RELOAD_TAB] = "F5";
```

3.) Edit that line to a different key code. I used:

```
action_accelerators[ACTION_RELOAD_TAB] = "<Control>F5";
```

4.) From the root directory of the source tree, compile the source code according to the GitHub website. You may have to install a few packages, but it is all well documented in the README.md file.

```
meson build 
cd build
ninja
```

5.) Replace the file io.elementary.terminal in /usr/bin with the newly compiled one in the build directory. That's it. Midnight Commander F5 works like a charm now.

This is a temporary fix, of course, and you need to recompile if a new version of Terminal is published in the AppCentre that still has that bug.

Comment: Thanks! Bummer that we have to change it in the source code. But it saves me a lot of frustration.

Thanks again!

Comment: I installed an update for the Elementary OS 6 Terminal yesterday (Dec 13, version 6.0.1), and the problem seems to have gone. I have had no issues using the function keys Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 0):

Just like **pigonthewing** said earlier, you need to edit the code and rebuild the app

I forked the code and i'll edit this line on every update

You can get it here: https://github.com/ForumPlayer/pantheon-terminal

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/25312)